# Не могу заполнить поле класса более чем одним словом C++

Tags: c++, списки

Мне нужно создать каталог файлов через линейный список, у каждого файла должно быть поле с именем (name), то что находится "внутри" файла (content), а также время его создания и счетчик сколько раз этот файл открывали. Реализовал интерфейс в консоли через _getch().

Почему-то когда пользователь вводит более одного слова для полей name или content через консоль, как я это реализовал, они все, начиная со второго, становятся новыми узлами в списке. Прошу помочь решить эту проблему. Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class file
{
    public:
        char name[64];
        char content[256];
        int count;
        int day, month, year, min, hour;

        file *next;
};

file *add(file *head) //добавление узла в список
{
    file *pv = new file;
    pv->next = 0;

    cout << "Name of the file: ";
    cin >> pv->name;

    pv->count = 0; 

    cout << "Input the content of the file: " << endl;;
    cin >> pv->content;

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    pv->day = st.wDay;
    pv->month = st.wMonth;
    pv->year = st.wYear;
    pv->hour = st.wHour;
    pv->min = st.wMinute;

    if(head)
    {
        file *temp = head;
        while(temp->next) 
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = pv;
    }
    else
        head = pv;
    return head;

}

void print(file *head) //печать списка
{
    if(head == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "The catalog is empty!";
    } 
    else
    {
        while(head != 0){
            cout << head->name << "\t" << "\t" << head->day << "." << head->month << "." << head->year << " " << head->hour << ":" << head->min << "\t" << "\t" << head->count << endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
}

void open_cont(file *head) //вывод "внутренностей" файла при вводе имени файла 
{
    file *ptr = head;
    char buff[64];

    cout << "Input the name of the file: ";
    cin >> buff;
    bool flag = true;

    while(head != NULL) 
    {
        if(strstr(ptr->name, buff))
        {
            system("cls");
            ptr->count++;
            cout << ptr->content;
            flag = false;   
        }

        head = head->next;
    }
    if(flag == true) cout << "No match!";

}

void clean(file *head) //удаление всего списка
{
    if(head != 0)
    {
        clean(head->next);
        delete head;
    }
}

int main()
{
    file *head = 0;

    char ckey;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "1 - Open file\n";
        cout << "2 - Add file to the catalog\n";
        cout << "3 - Open the catalog\n";
        cout << "5 - Exit\n";

        ckey = _getch();
        system("cls");

        if(ckey == '1') open_cont(head);

        else if(ckey == '2') head = add(head);

        else if(ckey == '3')
        {
            cout << "Name" << "\t" << "\t" << "Date" << "\t" << "\t" << "\t" << "Count" << endl;
            print(head);
        }
        else if(ckey == '5')
        {
            clean(head);    
        }
        else continue;
        _getch();

    } while(ckey != '5');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в работе `cin` он бьёт строку по пробелам

Хорошо видно на таком примере:

```
int main()
{
  char first[64];
  char second[64];
  std::cin>>first;
  std::cin>>second;
  std::cout << "First: " << first << " Second: " << second << "!\n";
}
```

Чтобы записывать строку с пробелами можно использовать `getline`

```
std::getline(std::cin, pv->name);
```